# Why is the Algolia index population process with Search Plus timing out?

Tags: plugin-searchplus

I'm at a loss here. Hopefully, someone here can shed some light into a Search Plus plugin and Algolia index population issue I'm having.

I'm able to add an item (page, blog post, product) to the item's respective index by editing the item but when I kick off the Search Plus index population process it quickly times out/fails. I have an index that literally has one item.  It populates the index when I edit it but the same item does not get added to the index when done via the Search Plus index population process. I'm skeptical that this is an Algolia API record size limit because I just described but I could be wrong.

I do see the following errors in the Craft admin console:

2019-03-21 22:38:52
Level   error
Category    application
Message Encountered an error running task 2591 (SearchPlus_Population), step 1 of 2: Trying to get property of non-object on line 519 of /craft/plugins/searchplus/services/SearchPlus_AlgoliaService.php

2019-03-21 22:38:52
Level   error
Category    php
Message Trying to get property of non-object (//craft/plugins/searchplus/services/SearchPlus_AlgoliaService.php:519)

I'm running Craft CMS 2.7.6 and Search Plus 1.5.2 on Nginx with PHP-FPM 7.1.  I checked the the Algolia credentials are correct. I have adjusted the Nginx configuration and PHP's timeout settings and max post size settings.

I reached out to the Search Plus developer and he replied once telling to adjust the PHP configuration and has been unresponsive since the initial exchange.

Hopefully, someone here can shed some light on this issue.

Thanks.
Sal

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to get property of non-object on line 519 of /craft/plugins/searchplus/services/SearchPlus_AlgoliaService.php

That sounds suspiciously like a bug in the plugin to me.  I'd recommend contacting the plugin's author and reporting it to them for further debugging:

https://transition.topshelfcraft.com/software/craft/searchplus/faq/how-can-i-get-support